# Power Pages Web API Bad Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, webapi

I'm trying to establish a web api connection between a power page and a dataverse table.

I keep getting 400 'Bad Request' errors, with the specific message being:

`{"error":{"code":"9004010A","message":"An unexpected error occurred while processing the request"}}`

I can't for the life of me see what's wrong with my request, but I understand the community here is good at finding mistakes.

I setup the ajax web api wrapper that Microsoft provides [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/configure/web-api-http-requests-handle-errors) and am calling the safeAjax method provided.

Can anyone spot an issue in my code, or know of another source of potential error?
Logical Table Name: 'crfb0_linkedin_posts'

```
const markComplete = () => {
    const url = "/_api/crfb0_linkedin_posts"

    const result = webapi.safeAjax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (res) {
        console.log("success", res)
      }
    })

    return result
  }

document.getElementById('completeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const button = this;
    const originalText = button.textContent;
    let result = markComplete()
    ...
  });
```

I have tried:

- reducing the request to the most basic GET request
- double-checking permissions
- restarting the portal

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the network traffic using browser tools to see the response details and figure out a potential reason for the error to happen. You can find more descriptive information here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-pages/configure/web-api-http-requests-handle-errors#error-codes